# How can i make the dialog boxes appear to the prompt that i put?

Tags: java

I been working on an assignment for my java programming class and need help on this.

The Assignment:

Write an application that plays “Guess the number” as follows:

-Your program chooses the number to be guessed by selecting a random integer in the range 1 to 1000.

-The application displays the prompt “Guess a number between 1 and 1000.”

-The player inputs the first guess. If the guess in incorrect, your program should display “Too high, try again” or “Too low, try again.”

-The program should prompt the user for next guess.

-When the user enters the correct answer, display “Congratulations you guessed the number” and the number of guesses and allow the user the play again or quit.

-For debugging purpose display your number.

-Use dialog boxes for input and output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;        
import java.util.Random;         
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class NumberGuess{
public static void main( String [] arg){
    int randNum = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
    String getGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number 
between 1-1000\n\n");
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(getGuess);
  int guesses;
    guesses = 0;
    String response;
  while (guess != randNum);
   
if (guess > randNum)
        {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Too high, try again.");
            guess = Integer.parseInt(getGuess);
            guesses++;
        }            
if (guess < randNum)
        {                         
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Too low, try again.");
            guesses++;
        }  
if (guess == randNum){
    guesses++;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations! The 
   correct " + "number is " + randNum + ",and you had" + guesses 
   + "guess.");
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

The code only show Enter a number between 1-1000 for the dialog boxes and not the other three dialog box. The box won't show even when I put JOptionPane.showMessageDialog instead of JOptionPane.showInputDialog, it will show the same thing. I'm stuck on this part and don't know how to make the other three dialog box appear.

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Try putting `else` before `if (guess < randNum)` and also putting `else` before `if (guess == randNum)`

Comment: Also replace the `;` (semicolon) with `{` after `while (guess != randNum)` in the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm "guessing" that you need to review while loops and do-while loops.

The code you posted didn't even compile.  After cleaning up all the syntax errors, I tested and retested to find all of the logic errors (I hope).

I'm also "guessing" that you wrote all the code you posted without running a single test.  Generally, you should write a little code, then test it.  When the code breaks, the problem is likely in that little bit you added.  You can focus on one small part of your program, rather than the whole thing.

Read the blog post, [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  It will teach you how to think about finding logical errors.

I cleaned up your where loop and added the missing lines of code.  You can't test for equality in the where clause because you'll never execute the information dialog.  I replaced the test with a boolean that I set to false after I show the information dialog.  How did I find this logical error?  Testing.

I added a do-while loop to ask the user if they want to play again.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I hope you learn something from reading it.  I know you're not going to turn my code in as homework because you'll have to explain why I did some of the things I did.  And we both know you don't want to be put on the spot like that.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumberGuess {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        do {
            int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
            int guess = getGuess("Enter a number between 1 - 1000");
            int guesses = 0;
            boolean running = true;
    
            while (running) {
                guesses++;
                if (guess > randNum) {
                    guess = getGuess("Too high, try again.");
                } else if (guess < randNum) {
                    guess = getGuess("Too low, try again.");
                } else {
                    showCongratulations(randNum, guesses);
                    running = false;
                }
            } 
        } while (playAgain() == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static int getGuess(String prompt) {
        String getGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
        if (getGuess == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(getGuess.trim());
    }
    
    private static void showCongratulations(int randNum, int guesses) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! The " 
                + "correct number is " + randNum
                + ", and you took " + guesses + " guesses.");
    }
    
    private static int playAgain() {
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?");
    }

}
```